# Getting raw ptr from a shared_ptr and make it shared again

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Why the code below do not works?

```
class A {};

void f(A* a) {
    shared_ptr<A> c(a);
}

int main() {
    auto a = make_shared<A>();
    auto b = a.get();
    f(b);
    return 0;
}
```

In the end of the scope of `f`, my program crashes. What could be causing this? Is there something that's trying to be deleted and does not exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two unrelated shared pointers that are both trying to manage the same resource.  That leads to undefined behaviour.  In particular, they're both going to try to delete the resource when they go out of scope.

In general, just don't do this :)

Comment: Oliver has it right.  Don't do this!  C++11 `std::shared_ptr` allows multiple sharings of the same thing, but only as long as all the shared_ptr's are aware of each other.  As soon as the raw pointer is pulled out, and then given ownership to a different shared_ptr, then there are independent owners, each with the understanding that they have sole ownership (or in the case of a shared_ptr, shared federated ownership, with two separate "federations").

Answer (score 4):

```
class A {};

void f(A* a) {
    shared_ptr<A> c(a);
}

int main() {
    auto a = make_shared<A>();
    auto b = a.get();
    f(b);
    return 0;
}
```

What's happening here is that your initial `make_shared()` is creating a `shared_ptr` which owns `A`. When you call `f(b)`, you are creating a second, unrelated shared pointer which *also* thinks it owns the same data. When the function call `f()` ends, the local shared ptr variable is destroyed; this checks whether the reference count is zero (which it will be), and so deletes the object. Then, when the main function ends, the destructor for the local variable `a` runs, checks that the reference count is zero (again, it will be), and so tries to delete the same data a second time. This double-delete is what is causing the crash.

There are a couple of solutions to this: the easiest is simply not to deal with raw pointers, and pass the `shared_ptr` directly to `f()`. Then the reference counting will work correctly and the data will only be destroyed once.

Another way of doing this is to have your class `A` publicly inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this`. Then you can use the `shared_from_this()` method to "recover" a shared pointer (with correct reference counting) from a raw pointer, i.e.

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {};

void f(A* a) {
    shared_ptr<A> c = a->shared_from_this();
}
```

You can read about `enable_shared_from_this` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).